# Combine include and exclude file mask in WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I've used the WinSCP .NET assembly to download files from my FTP for a while with a simple FileMask: `"|*/"`, as I don't want it to traverse subdirectories. This works well, but now I'm trying to add another filemask to only download files that are have been modified after a certain date, but I'm having issues with using multiple file masks.

Writing it like this, not unexpectedly, just overwrites the `FileMask` property on the object:

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "|*/";  // don't download subdirs
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=" + date; // only get files updated after date
```

and using it like this, as people have specified and how it's written in some docs:

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "|*/"; "*>=" + date;
```

gives me the error *"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."*

Is there any other way to separate the two file masks, and make sure both are in usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of [WinSCP file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) is `include|exclude`.

So you want: `*>=date|*/`

In C# code that would be:

```
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=" + date + "|*/";
```

See [Include and exclude masks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#include_exclude).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!